# Read the incoming sms and pass the message body to android application

Tags: android, sms, message, android-cursor

I am developing an android application in which I want to read the sms and pass the data to my application.

I tried many ways but cant't figure it out. Here is what I am doing. Is something wrong in my code.

```
 String msg_body = "";
       Uri my_uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
       Cursor readFstSms = v.getContext().getContentResolver().query(my_uri, null, null, null, null);
       if(readFstSms.moveToFirst())
       {
           msg_body = readFstSms.getString(readFstSms.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
       }
       readFstSms.close();
       Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + msg_body);
       Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
       mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
       startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`
in my manifest file but still can't find the solution

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it. If that's not the issue, you need to provide a lot more detail as to how exactly it's not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But still it is not solving problem. Can anyone help me with this problem. I want to deploy this app

Comment: Help you with what? You haven't even said what the problem is. Does it not read what you expect it to? Does it not read anything? Does it not start the `Activity`? Does it crash? Does your phone explode? What? "cant't figure it out" is not an adequate problem statement.

Comment: It does not store my message body which I need to retrive from message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the read permissions for the app through manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

And you need a BroadcastReciever which  should be declared in manifest with the intent filter `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`
'

Once the reciever starts working, You can handle the recieved SMS in the onRecieve callback method of that BroadcastReceiver.

```
if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] messages = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);

                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();

 Toast.makeText(context, body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```